# target iframe from different page in php or javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am creating a template demo bar, where people can view my created web themes. User will click preview button on one page and will be able to see theme in iframe in another page. 
Below is the code for link page

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<a href="http://site/demobar?theme=http://www.template.com">preview</a>
</body>
</html>
```

and then on demo page I get the iframe

```
<iframe src="<?php echo $_GET['theme']; ?>" style="width:100vw; height:100vh;"></iframe>
```

This works ok, but my problem is in returning url which displays the URL:

> http://site/demobar/?theme=http://www.template.com

I want template name instead of template address in URL

> http://site/demobar/?theme=themeName

How can I achieve this!!, is there any other alternative with javascript!

Comment: I don't see how the first url works as it doesn't include the theme name? If you just want to avoid the full url in the address bar, you can inject part of it automatically... `<iframe src="http://www.template.com/<?php echo $_GET['theme']; ?>" style="width:100vw; height:100vh;"></iframe>`

Comment: it is helpful, if i just want to remove first few part of URL, there can be multiple different URL, storing all addresses in an array and then calling the array index number is close to what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, set up an array with possible themes, and pick the appropriate one based on the `theme` parameter...

```
<?php 
    $themes = array(
        "theme" => "http://www.theme.com/",
        "othertheme" => "http://www.some-other-theme.com/",
    );
    $themeAddress = $themes[$_GET['theme']];
?>
```

Next, generate the iframe with reference to the url...

```
<iframe src="<?php echo $themeAddress; ?>" style="width:100vw; height:100vh;"></iframe>
```

Then call the url with the appropriate theme name:

> http://site/demobar/?theme=othertheme

Comment: exactly what I wanted.